# Is it possible with CSS to make text's color fade between two colors?

Tags: html, css

I'm hoping to achieve the effect in the following design.

[image]

Possible without using images?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8k66bwbk/

```
.blue-fade
{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;  
    color: #1ba0d7;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you want something like that?

```css
.blue-fade {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100; 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1ba0d7, #002d3f);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<p class="blue-fade">
368%
</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9dx4fcrz/

Answer (score 2):

You can also change fade by opacity. Here is an example with hover.

```css
.blue-fade
{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;  
    color: #1ba0d7;   
}

.blue-fade:hover {
   opacity: 0.5;
 }
```

```html
<h2 class="blue-fade">
Subheadline
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, what you are asking for is not supported in Firefox, so in order for my example to work you must use Chrome.

[Example](http://codepen.io/HTMLNoob/pen/yejZjR)

`

```css
h1{ font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#999, #222);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Text</h1>
```